# calling specific nodes to display images - d3 network graph

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nodes, force-layout

I'm trying to show some images whenever users hover on specific nodes only.
Here's my snippet codes and json :

```js
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
       .data(json.nodes)
       .enter().append("g")
       .attr("class", "node")
       .call(force.drag)
       .on("mouseover", function(d) {

          if(d.source === 0) {

          div.transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", .9);

          var string = 
          "<img src=\"images/psimg/DELREGO-B001.jpg\"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+
          "<img src=\"images/psimg/DELREGO-R001.jpg\"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
          "<img src=\"images/psimg/DELREGO-T001.jpg\"/>";

          div.html(string)
          .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")     
          .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 50) + "px")
          .style("font-color", "white");
}

    {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "name": "Delonix regia",
          "group": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "Semarak Api",
          "group": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "Fabaceae",
          "group": 1
        },
    ...
      ],
      "links": [
        {
          "source": 0,
          "target": 0,
          "value": 10
        },
        {
          "source": 1,
          "target": 0,
          "value": 10
        },
    ...
      ]
    }
```

So, that coding works perfectly without `if(d.source === 0){}` but that means images will be shown whenever users hover to any nodes. I just need that images will only be shown when users hover to nodes with `source = 0`.

I cannot get any graph displayed by using the snippet above. 
Tried with `===` or `==` but no changes.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `source` is not a property of the node datum. Besides that, your requirement (*"I just need that images will only be shown when users hover to nodes with source = 0"*) makes no sense: that `source` is the index of the node. So, what do you want? Show images for every node except the first one?

Comment: I thought that is how I can access to the source node, no? I need images to show at the first node only which is the node with source = 0. I'm a bit confused about nodes `d`.

Comment: Use `d.index === 0`.

Comment: That works! I thought we need to go through `d.source` first? I tried `d.source.index` but it wasn't working. Thanks a lot.